# Server Certificate .pfx work locally but doesn't work after publish on iis10

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

i made certificate authentication in .Net core (api core) using server certificate .pfx file and this works well locally but doesn't work after publish the code and the .pfx file on iis , this always allow me to access the service , either i put the client certificate on the browser or not

Comment: If you don't edit the question to reveal your IIS settings (such as what authentication methods are enabled/disabled), this question cannot be answered.

Comment: How did it not work? Return insecurity message? How did you set the server certificate on server and client certificate on pc?